# Xamarin.Android in C# Visual Studio: Multiple Spinners using the very same adapter?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have a layout that I want to inflate multiple times to an `Alertdialog`. I have a list to hold the inflated views and I created an `Adapter` from a resource defined in Resources/values/Strings.xml.
This is the relevant part of Strings.xml:

```
<string name="day_prompt">Choose a day</string>
<string-array name="days_array">
  <item>Monday</item>
  <item>Tuesday</item>
  <item>Wednesday</item>
  <item>Thursday</item>
  <item>Friday</item>
  <item>Saturday</item>
  <item>Sunday</item>
</string-array>
```

And here is the code used to create an adpter and a list:

```
//create a list to hold Views
List<View> chooseElements = new List<View>();
//create a new adapter to be fed with data defined in vals/Strings
var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.days_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
//set its source to prev mentioned 
                adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++)
    {
         //creating a custom number of elements
         SetUpItems(Resource.Id.dayPicker, Resource.Layout.ChoosingDay, alertHolder, adapter, chooseElements);  
    }
```

I want to find the id of a `Spinner` element inside the actual (latest) `ViewGroup` element in the list, which I manage to do. My problem is, however, that I can only set the adapter of the `Spinner` created first, all the other elements appear not the have an adapter attached, as if *one adapter* can only be used for *only one* element.
Here is the relevant code:

```
void SetUpItems(int idOfSpinner, int idOfElement, View alertDialogHolder, ArrayAdapter ad, List<View> list)
    {
        list.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(idOfElement, alertDialogHolder.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainHolder)));
        #region Spinner
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        //spinner  = alertDialogHolder.FindViewById<Spinner>(idOfSpinner);
        spinner = list[list.Count - 1].FindViewById<Spinner>(idOfSpinner);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(Spinner_ItemSelected);
        //var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.days_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        //adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = ad;
        #endregion
    }
```

I'm fairly new to Xamarin, so I don't really know how to handle multiple `Spinners` with the same adapter (or if it is actually possible). I tried many solutions to no avail and I could not find any resource on handling multiple `Spinner`s with the same adapter. Could someone give me some advice on this?

Comment: So, you have several `Spinner`s in one view and only the first can be successfully set the adapter, the others with the same adapter don't work?

Comment: Yes, but it is a bit more complex than that: I create the `Spinner` elements through _inflation_ and although I set the adapter for all of them, only the first seems to have an adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem in the future, I found a solution. It is not very clean, but it works. Sorry, I'm not a very experienced developer.

The main problem seems to have been with the following code:

```
 spinner = list[list.Count - 1].FindViewById<Spinner>(idOfSpinner);
```

which is not problematic per se, but if you want to assign the view found by FindViewById to other elements as well, you gonna face problems, as *all the generated elements will have the same ID*. For some reason, this does not count as an error (not even a warning) so your program will compile and solve the issue by always returning the very first element with the requested ID from the list. In practical terms, this means that in programs like mine, the very same first element will get re-defined over and over again, while the other elements are ignored.

The problem can be solved if you assign a new ID programmarically to your element. In my code, I used lists so that I can access each element for future data transfer to another activity, but I guess it is possible to do it w/o it, the key element in assigning a new unique ID.

```
list.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(idOfElement, alertDialogHolder.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainHolder)));

//creating a temp list for spinners
List<Spinner> spinners = new List<Spinner>();

//adding a new element
spinners.Add(new Spinner(this));

//capturing the current element, this way, I dont have to re-call it every time
int currentElement = spinners.Count - 1;

//assign a new lineear layout from another list
spinners[currentElement] = list[list.Count - 1].FindViewById<Spinner>(idOfSpinner);

//IMPORTANT: generate a new UNIQUE id 
spinners[currentElement].Id = View.GenerateViewId();

//subscribe to the event
spinners[currentElement].ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(Spinner_ItemSelected);

//set the adapter
spinners[currentElement].Adapter = ad;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use ActionSheet? Follow this [link](https://github.com/MyueX/Xamarin.ActionSheet/blob/master/ActionSheetTest/ActionSheetTest/MainActivity.cs) you will have a solution on what you looking for.

Have a look the code sample

```
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.ActionSheet;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;

namespace ActionSheetTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "ActionSheetTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity,ActionSheet.IActionSheetListener
    {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            var actionSheet = new ActionSheet ();
            actionSheet.Other_Button_Title = new List<string> (){ "Option1", "Option2" };
            actionSheet.SetActionSheetListener (this);
            actionSheet.Show (SupportFragmentManager);
        };
    }

    public void onDismiss (ActionSheet actionSheet, bool isCancel)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("onDismiss");
    }

    public void onOtherButtonClick (ActionSheet actionSheet, int index)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine (index);
    }
}
}
```